# Configurable keycloak client secret in docker-compose

Tags: vue.js, authentication, vuejs2, keycloak

I am using Keycloak to authenticate a Vue app that is running on Docker. Currently, my configuration includes using `grant_type=password` along with `client-id` and `client-secret` to authenticate a client.

Because I want to make `client-secret` configurable, what is the best way to use keycloak `client-secret` in docker-compose.

Comment: Client secret in the SPA (Vue) app? Do you understand that any user can find that client secret in the SPA source code? Also direct access grant is not very secure. Your whole implementation doesn't seems to be secure. Why you can't use good secure standard flow for SPA apps `Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)` ? You won't have a this problem with client secret.